# update adb on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, adb

I'm want to use [`scrcpy`](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) in Raspberry Pi 4 for connection to tablet(Android 11) with Wireless debugging. I know that first you need to `adb pair` device before you can `adb connect`, but when I try to pair my device I'm getting this error:

```
$ adb pair
adb: unknown command pair
```

Seems like `adb` is outdated in Ubuntu 21.10 `APT` package repository

```
$ adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 28.0.2-debian
Installed as /usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb
```

```
$ apt-cache policy adb
adb:
  Installed: 1:10.0.0+r36-7
  Candidate: 1:10.0.0+r36-7
  Version table:
 *** 1:10.0.0+r36-7 500
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports impish/universe arm64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

How can I install newest version of `adb` for `arm64`?